# A heuristic explanation of the Curse of Dimensionality

Tags: functions, machine-learning

From *Principles and Theory for Data Mining and Machine Learning*, Clarke et al. (2009):

> This phrase [the "Curse of Dimensionality"] was first used by Bellman (1961)... The result is that
>   difficulty outstrips conventional data gathering even for what one
>   would expect were relatively benign dimensions. A heuristic way to
>   look at this is to think of real functions of $x$, of $y$, and of the
>   pair $(x, y)$. Real functions $f$, $g$ of a single variable represent
>   only a vanishingly small fraction of the functions $k$ of $(x, y)$.
>   Indeed, they can be embedded by writing $k(x, y) = f(x) + g(y)$.
>   Estimating an arbitrary function of two variables is more than twice
>   as hard as estimating two arbitrary functions of one variable.

How am I supposed to deduce that last sentence? I particularly don't understand the meaning of the "embedding" with the $+$ sign.

I'm sorry if not enough effort is seemingly put into this, but I'm not sure how to display effort when it's an issue of reading comprehension.

Comment: A function of a single variable can be so "embedded" in the space of functions of two variables by taking either $f = 0$ or $g = 0$. So just analyzing functions of the form $k(x,y) = f(x) + g(y)$ is "twice as hard" as estimating functions of a single variable, and these are only a small part of the varied ways we might *combine* such single-variable functions to get a two-variable one (for example, we might multiply, or compose two such functions as well).